# Dynamic properties in Java from xml

Tags: java, xml

I'm fiddling around with an idea but can't get a grip on it.

I have an xml file with 100+ properties defining the runtime environment of a somewhat large program. These are exposed as variables through a class . At the moment, for each option in the xml file, there is a variable in the class plus public getter and private setter.

Each time we need a new option, we have to define it in the xml file and create the variable plus methods in the RuntimenEnvironment class.

Now, what I would like to do is something like this: I want to rewrite the class in such a way, that it exposes new options from the xml file as vars without having to touch the class.

My xml file uses this structure:

```
<option>
  <name>theName</name>
  <type>eg int</type>
  <value>20</value>
  <constant>THE_NAME</constant>
</option>
```

Can I write code in java that dynamically creates the vars at runtime and exposes them through a method without actually writing the method?

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options I could think of are:

- If the name is unique a map can be populated with name as the key.
- If you are interested only in options then a list of Options can be
  populated from the XML.

Below is the sample code implemented with SAX parser

**Handler Class**

```
public class OptionsParser extends DefaultHandler {
    private final StringBuilder valueBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    private final Map<String, Option> resultAsMap = new HashMap<String, Option>();
    private final List<Option> options = new ArrayList<Option>();

    //variable to store the values from xml temporarily
    private Option temp;

    public List<Option> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public Map<String, Option> getResultAsMap() {
        return resultAsMap;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName,
            final Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if("option".equalsIgnoreCase(qName)) {
            temp = new Option();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        //read the value into a string to set them to option object
        final String value = valueBuffer.toString().trim();
        switch (qName) {
        case "name":
            temp.setName(value);
            // set the value into map and name of the option is the key
            resultAsMap.put(value, temp);
            break;
        case "type":
            temp.setType(value);
            break;
        case "value":
            temp.setValue(value);
            break;
        case "constant":
            temp.setConstant(value);
            break;
        case "option":
            // this is the end of option tag add it to the list
            options.add(temp);
            temp = null;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        //reset the buffer after every iteration
        valueBuffer.setLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(final char[] ch, final int start, final int length)
            throws SAXException {
        //read the value into a buffer
        valueBuffer.append(ch, start, length);
    }
}
```

**Option POJO**

```
public class Option {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String value;
    private String constant;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getConstant() {
        return constant;
    }

    public void setConstant(String constant) {
        this.constant = constant;
    }
}
```

**Input XML**

```
<options>
    <option>
        <name>option1</name>
        <type>int</type>
        <value>20</value>
        <constant>const1</constant>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name>option2</name>
        <type>string</type>
        <value>testValue</value>
        <constant>const2</constant>
    </option>
</options>
```

**Sample Main class**

```
public class ParseXML {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final OptionsParser handler = new OptionsParser();
            try {
                SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
                        .parse("C:/luna/sample/inputs/options.xml", handler);
            } catch (SAXException | IOException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
                System.err.println("Somethig went wrong while parsing the input file the exception is -- " + e.getMessage() + " -- ");
            }
            Map<String, Option> result = handler.getResultAsMap();
            Collection<Option> values = result.values();
            for (Option option : values) {
                System.out.println(option.getName());
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll talk about json configuration files. But XML should also be similar. Jackson provides way to deserialise JSON and create dynamic object.
If the names of your options (`theName`) are unique, you can create dynamic beans. Your xml will then look like:

```
<theName>
  <type>eg int</type>
  <value>20</value>
  <constant>THE_NAME</constant>
</theName>
```

See, I am talking about json, so its actually:

```
theName: {
      type: "int"
      value: 20
      constant: "THE_NAME" }
```

Dynamic beans contain a Map, so your options will be stored in a `Map<String, Option>`, where `Option` is a POJO containing `type`, `value` and `constant` fields.
You should be able to access your options by iterating the map. There is no need to create variables dynamically.
This [blog entry](http://sinujohn.wordpress.com/2014/09/29/jackson-json-and-dynamic-json-creations/) has got details about how to convert json to POJO